# Determine the parallel plane to segment

Tags: geometry

Between the planes containing the line r of equation $3x + y = 3x + z - 1 = 0$, determine the one parallel to the segment AB with $A (1,2,0)$ and $B (0,3, -2)$. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the equation of the line is $r=(0,0,1)+t(1/3,-1,-1)$ i.e. the parallel vector to the line and plane is $u=(3,-1,-1)$ and the second parallel to the plane is $v=B-A$ and hence the normal is $n=u ×v$  and the plane passes through $(0,0,1)$ Then
$$[(x,y,z)-(0,0,1)].n=0$$

Comment: $v=B-A$? Or $v=(x,y,z)-A$?

Comment: @mark i complete it

Comment: are $n=u\ x \ v$ the vector product?

Comment: yes it is @Mark Glad to help out